# Override in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Func2 is called when I click on button . Why i don't get any popup? Should I see both alert alert ("override1") and alert ("override2") after the first one?

```
// JavaScript Document
function person(name, surname) {
    this.name = "";
    this.surname = "";
    this.age = "11";
    this.setName(name);
    this.setSurname(surname);
    //alert('Person instantiated'); 
}
person.prototype.setName = function(name) {
    this.name = "Sir1" + name;
}
person.prototype.setSurname = function(surname) {
    this.surname = "-" + surname;
}
person.prototype.setAge = function(newAge) {
    this.age = newAge;
}
person.prototype.show = function() {
    alert("override1");
}
function employee(name, surname, company) {
    //if (arguments[0] === inheriting) return;
    person.call(this, name, surname); // -> override del costruttore
    //this.name = "Sir2"+name;
    this.company = company;
};
employee.prototype.show = function() {
    person.prototype.show;
    alert("override2");
}
function test2() {
    employee.prototype = new person();
    // correct the constructor pointer because it points to Person  
    employee.prototype.constructor = employee;
    // Crea un oggetto impiegato da persona
    impiegato = new employee("Antonio", "Di Maio", "Consuldimo");
    //impiegato.show();
    impiegato.show();
}​
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you should review the [markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) page. A well-written question will get you well-written answers.

Comment: What button?  You have not posted the code that calls "test2()"

Comment: <button onclick="test2()">
<p>Test 1</p>
</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `test2()` you're replacing the entire `employee.prototype` with an instance of `person`, thus overwriting the `employee.prototype.show` function you've defined previously with the one inherited from `person`. Also, as stated in the answer by codebox, in `employee.prototype.show()` you're not calling `person.prototype.show()`, but merely evaluating it in void context, which has no effect at all.

You'll have to set `employee`'s parent *before* you define any additional methods on its prototype:

```
employee.prototype = new person();
employee.prototype.constructor = employee;
employee.prototype.show = function() { ... }
```

Also, when you call your parent's method, you need to supply the correct context yourself:

```
person.prototype.show.call(this);
```

Comment: @user1343454: Code ordering is important. What you're doing to `employee.prototype` is like: `array=[1]; array.push(2); array=[]; array.push(3);`.

Comment: Thanks. Lanzz suggestion helped.

Answer (score 0):

In `employee.prototype.show` you are not calling the `person.prototype.show` method - change it to this:

```
employee.prototype.show = function() {
     person.prototype.show();  
     alert ("override2");
 }
```

Comment: The method will get `person.prototype` as `this` which is really unexpected.

Comment: Your funtion seems to be the same I have written in my code :(

Comment: Done but I still see only overide1 alert message :(

Comment: employee.prototype.show = function()
           {
            alert ("override2");
             person.prototype.show();
           };